# Patterns in Norm-Euclidean fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am reading 'Algebraic Number Theory' by Chapman and Hall.

They (page 94) describe the two sequences:

$-1,-2,-3,-7,-11$

$2,3,5,6,7,11,13,17,19,21,29,33,37,41,55,73$

However the numbers mean nothing to me! Can someone explain?

---

Following the accepted answer, these numbers can be found at:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Norm-Euclidean_fields

What I meant to ask is:

> Is there any known pattern to them?

I have read that they are '[almost-integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number#Almost_integers_and_Ramanujan's_constant)', but then so is $-163$.

I also vaguely recall a notion that a bounding box doesn't overlap (hence **Unique** Factorization Domain), and I was wondering in any progress had been made in determining when a box might overlap or not, as this approach seems simpler than finding 'almost-integers'.

Comment: Can you provide some context from the book?

Comment: I haven't read the book, but I doubt they just list the sequences with no context. What does the book say about these two sequences?

Comment: @shardulc; something about Euclidean-norms'

Comment: @JonMarkPerry **something**? Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: theorem 4.19 states 'the ring of integers of $mathbb{Q\sqrt(d)$..., but the next paragraph says 'we cannot prove this theorem here'. so i'm looking for a proof of it

Comment: As you are someone who has frequently contributed to the OEIS, I'm surprised you didn't think to look there first. Anytime a sequence of numbers means nothing to you, that's the first place to look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://oeis.org/A048981: Squarefree values of n for which the quadratic field $Q[ \sqrt{n}]$  is norm-Euclidean.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm-Euclidean_field#Norm-Euclidean_fields